# Random crash while scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash, realm

I have an app that has a tableView that can have hundreds of cells, and I got a random crash while doing a simple scrolling, while disconnected from Xcode.

The table uses an array of objects that are stored in Realm. Most of the cells are populated from that Array, except the row 0, that has a summary and does a read of a Realm Object directly.

I am trying to replicate the crash (with heavy ninja-scrolling) without success

This is the snippet of code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SummaryCell", for: indexPath) as! SummaryCell
            let count = "\(ItemsManager.shared.allActiveItems.count)" // ** Read from Realm **         
            cell.labellTotal.text = count
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
            cell.labelTag.text = itemsArray[indexPath.row - 1]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

I imported the crashLog to Xcode/Devices and it was symbolicated partially, but I don't get a clear idea how what happened. (the build was done in the same Mac)

The backtrace shows the access to CellForRow(atIndexPath:), and then several instances of Realm.   The last part of the log I attached shows a crash in thread 0, but it is not very helpful (Thread 0 Crashed:)

Any idea of what may be wrong?

This is a summary of the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x184966d8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x183b205ec objc_exception_throw + 55
2   Realm                           0x103af598c 0x1039d4000 + 1186188
3   Realm                           0x103af77c8 0x1039d4000 + 1193928
4   Realm                           0x103af7798 0x1039d4000 + 1193880
5   App Name Dev                    0x1027cd180 ItemsViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 1495424 (ItemsViewController.swift:274)
6   App Name Dev                    0x1027ce3ec @objc ItemsViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 1500140 (ItemsViewController.swift:0)
7   UIKit                           0x18e6400cc -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 667


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001843ed2ec __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001845926a8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018435bd0c abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183af72c8 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183af7470 default_unexpected_handler+ 5232 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183b208d4 _objc_terminate+ 35028 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183b1137c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 111484 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000183b10f78 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183b207ac objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018482ce18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 664
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000186811020 GSEventRunModal + 100
11  UIKit                           0x000000018e849758 UIApplicationMain + 236
12  App Name Dev                    0x0000000102702b6c main + 666476 (AppDelegate.swift:20)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001842bdfc0 start + 4
```

Comment: can you show line no 274 in `ItemsViewController.swift`?

Comment: Hi @Kamran.   I omitted some of the lines for clarity.  Line 274 is a  call to a method with a RegEx and Formatter for the item tag (String)           cell.labelTag.text = TagMatcher.matchTag(tagNumber: item.tagNumber)![TagMatcher.MATCH_VISUAL]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be because of few things:

1. You work with Realm in incorrect thread
2. You work with Realm synchronously and it block main thread
3. You work with Realm async and don't cancel operation if cell is reusing and operation is still in progress

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is your use of force casting (`as!`). Change this line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SummaryCell", for: indexPath) as! SummaryCell
```

To:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SummaryCell", for: indexPath) as? SummaryCell else {
  fatalError("Unable to dequeue cell with identifier 'SummaryCell'. Exiting.")
}
```

Make the same change to the other call to `tableView.dequeueReusableCell()`. Then re-run your code and see what happens.

If the force-cast is the problem you'll still crash, but you will see a very clear error in the console telling you why you crashed.

Comment: For clarity - „as!” Is a force cast, not force unwrap. And adding `fatalError` will also crash the app.

Comment: @Losiowaty, wrong term. Thanks for correcting me. (I edited my answer.) Indeed it will crash the app, but it will log a very clear error to the console and remove all doubt as to why it crashed. It's a development tool, not a production solution.

Comment: Yeah, I get that - it's just an important thing, worth mentioning in the answer. It may not help OP though, as he said that he hasn't succeeded in reproducing this bug himself.